# Android Marshmallow Permission for my eclipse project not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I have created an application using eclipse IDE. And now its crashing on Marshmallow for various permissions say contact. After lot of searching I come up with no result.

It is showing error in `checkSelfPermission`, `requestPermissions` etc. on CONTACT from Manifest.permission.CONTACTS.

I think the solutions are working on android studio projects. So let me know same for eclipse project if any one know it.
 [image]

Comment: add your code how you are asking permissions

Comment: Hello Sohail, Please find attachment on question or click here : http://i.stack.imgur.com/X8C34.png

Comment: Try this it may be help you:-http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Full working demo**

You are making mistake of here there is no permission like `CONTACTS` only there is `READ_CONTACTS` and `WRITE_CONTACTS`

correct is `Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS;` instead of `Manifest.permission.CONTACTS;`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context context;
    private Button button;
    private static final int REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION = 123;
    private String permission = Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (CheckPermission(MainActivity.this, permission)) {
                    // you have permission go ahead
                    YouCanReadContactNow();
                } else {
                    // you do not have permission go request runtime permissions
                    RequestPermission(MainActivity.this, permission, REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void YouCanReadContactNow() {
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

        switch (permsRequestCode) {
            case REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // you have permission go ahead
                    YouCanReadContactNow();
                } else {
                    // you do not have permission show toast.
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void RequestPermission(Activity thisActivity, String Permission, int Code) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Permission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                    Permission)) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                        new String[]{Permission},
                        Code);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean CheckPermission(Context context, String Permission) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Request contact permissions"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Sohil. But I am getting issues on :
The method checkSelfPermission(Activity, String) is undefined for the type ContextCompat , 

The method shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Activity, String) is undefined for the type ActivityCompat , 

The method requestPermissions(Activity, String[], int) is undefined for the type ActivityCompat , 

The method checkSelfPermission(Context, String) is undefined for the type ContextCompat

Comment: have you add the appcompat v4 lib?

Comment: why didt you move to the android studio?

Comment: No Sohail, It is having appcompat_v7 library. And the project is build with eclipse so trying there. And dont have knowledge about Android studio. Will install and study

Comment: How can the answer is acceptable if it is only for android studio. question was asked for eclipse only

Answer (score 0):

i m not finding anywhere this permission: `Manifest.permission.CONTACTS`

there is only two contact permission:

1. READ_CONTACTS
2. WRITE_CONTACTS

you should use this two. only CONTACTS will give you error.

Comment: Hello Sagar, Actaully i followed one sample after googling and that code was from there only. I have implemented 
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
     Manifest.permission_group.CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

but getting red line error : The method checkSelfPermission(HomeActivity, String) is undefined for the type ContextCompat

Answer (score 0):

Update last version **Android Support Repository**
[image]

And in **Android Private Library** only one and last version android-support-v4.jar added.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Appart from the `READ_CONTACTS`/`WRITE_CONTACTS` issue: in order to solve the `checkSelfPermission() not found` **in Eclipse** you can add `android-support-compat.jar` as taken from https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-compat/tree/28.0.0 to the `libs` folder of your Eclipse project and compile again.