# ActivityCompat can't find .checkSelfPermission in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have create program which can send message. when I use Activity.checkSelfPermission,  it show the error like "The method checkSelfPermission(MainActivity, String) is undefined for the type ActivityCompat". I have import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat already. My target API 23 and compile with API 23 also. How to solve it?

[image]

[image]

Below is the real code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final int MY_PERMISSION_SEND_SMS = 10;
public EditText edSMS, edPhone;
public Button btnSent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edSMS = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edPhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    btnSent = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    onCheckPermission();
}

private void onCheckPermission() {
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermission(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, MY_PERMISSION_SEND_SMS);
    }       
    else {
        sentMessage();
    }
}
private void sentMessage() {
    btnSent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String phoneNumber = edPhone.getText().toString();
            String SMS = edSMS.getText().toString();
            if(((phoneNumber.length() == 10) || (phoneNumber.length()==9)) && phoneNumber.length()>0){
                SmsManager smsText = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsText.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, SMS, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SMS was sent successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                edPhone.setText("");
                edSMS.setText("");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please check your " + "phone number again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){
    switch (requestCode){
        case MY_PERMISSION_SEND_SMS:
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Read Contacts permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                sentMessage();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Read Contacts permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)){
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).
                    setTitle("Request Permission SMS").
                    setMessage(" You must set permission to access this application").show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Switch to `ANDROID STUDIO`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Marshmallow Permission for my eclipse project not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342237/android-marshmallow-permission-for-my-eclipse-project-not-working)

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya no more solution?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the method `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission() not found` in Eclipse you can simply add `android-support-compat.jar` as taken from https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-compat/tree/28.0.0 to the `libs` folder of your Eclipse project and compile again.

Answer (score -1):

just use `support.v7` (`import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;`),this is well be rolved

by the way?why do you still use eclipse now?just use Android studio,it's better so much.

Comment: I will try with Android Studio.

Comment: have to disagree with "it's better". It is different. each IDE has its advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: any have any solution for eclipse.